# How to access (and modify) the elements of the same matrix using p threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, matrix, synchronization

I have a matrix Image MxN and I want to apply on it a matrix filter of 5x5 (like in this gif https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:2D_Convolution_Animation.gif)
I am taking an element from position i,j in the matrix, add the filter on it and its surrounding elements and calculate the new product.
I'm using p threads to do that and each threads gets assigned what columns/rows it will apply the filter to.
Currently I have 2 matrices: - image for the given  MxN matrix (that gets 2 borders on each side copying the elements on the side to make the filter application easier).
- filteredImage, where I store the result of the filter applied on each element of the image

My question is: how can I modify my functions below to stop using filteredImage and to operate directly on the matrix Image?

```
int operation(int x_coord, int y_coord) {
    int res = 0;
    int offset = n / 2;

    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < m; y++) {
            res += image[x_coord - offset + x][y_coord - offset + y] * filter[x][y];
        }
    }
    return res;
}

void threadTask(int start, int end) {

    if (M > N) {
        for (int j = start; j < end; j++) {
            for (int i = 2; i < N + 2; i++) {
                filteredImage[i][j] = operation(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            for (int j = 2; j < M + 2; j++) {
                filteredImage[i][j] = operation(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}


void paralel() {
    thread threads[16]; //max nr of p
    int start = 2;
    int end;
    int nrMax;
    int operationsPerThread;
    int rest;
    nrMax = max(N, M);
    operationsPerThread = nrMax / p;
    rest = nrMax % p;

    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
    {
        end = start + operationsPerThread;
        if (rest > 0) {
            rest--;
            end++;
        }
        threads[i] = thread(threadTask, start, end);
        start = end;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        threads[i].join();
    }
 
}



---
```

bordering:
image[0][0] = image[0][1] = image[1][0] = image[1][1] = image[2][2];

```
image[N + 3][0] = image[N + 2][0] = image[N + 3][1] = image[N + 2][1] = image[N + 1][2];

image[0][M + 2] = image[1][M + 2] = image[0][M + 3] = image[1][M + 3] = image[2][M + 1];

image[N + 2][M + 2] = image[N + 3][M + 2] = image[N + 3][M + 3] = image[N + 3][M + 2] = image[N + 2][M + 3] = image[N + 1][M + 1];
```

the matrices:
int image[N + 4][M + 4], filter[n][m], filteredImage[N + 4][M + 4];

I was thinking of using a barrier so that:
Each threads copies each frontier/the elements it needs to use, there's a barrier and it waits for the other threads to reach the barrier, then the elements in Image are updated using the copied elements.
The only function I need to change is threadTask.

I'm not quite sure how to implement this and I also don't know if this is the most efficient method (I want to copy as few elements as possible).

Any help is very appreciated. Thank you

Comment: This has nothing to do with threads. Even with a single thread you can't do that. If you update a value in `image`, it would throw off computations for neighboring cells. You'd just get incorrect result.

Comment: You don't need a full-sized second matrix, but you need at least an Nx3 strip. You compute and write new values for columns 0, 1 and 2 into this strip. At this point, no further computation needs original values in column 0, so you could copy new values from column 0 of the strip back into the original matrix, and use that space to hold new values for column 3. And so on - columns of the strip used in a circular-buffer fashion to move over the original matrix. This won't parallelize well though; your original approach of having two full matrices would work best for parallel computations.

Comment: I guess you could split the matrix into `p` vertical sections, and have each thread work on its section. Except that, before they start writing, each thread would need to copy two columns worth of data to the right of its section, because the other thread would overwrite them soon.